# Nginx rewrite syntax

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I've seen a bunch of ngnix rewrites that have syntax like this:

```
server {
    server_name  www.example.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://example.com$1 permanent;
}
```

I don't understand the `^(.*)` part.  Does the `^` take everything after the TLD of the uri?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `^` does indeed match at the beginning of the string. In the case of nginx's `rewrite` directive this means the beginning of the path component of the actual URI. Unfortunately nginx's documentation is slightly incorrect. Quoting from http://www.nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite :

> If the specified regular expression matches a URI, the URI is changed as specified in the replacement string.

However, this is technically wrong. `rewrite` does not match the whole URI/URL but only its path component (which always starts with a `/` even if the user only enters e.g. `http://www.example.com` instead of `http://www.example.com/`). Therefore `rewrite ^(.*) http://example.com$1 permanent;` does not turn into `http://example.comwww.example.com`.

Comment: No. Both URI and URL refer to the whole thing (schema://host/path...). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url . What nginx matches is neither the URL nor the URI but only the path component of the URI/URL. In my example the URI/URL starts with "h", the path component with "/".

Comment: And even if you mean to say that the path component in a URL is different from a path component in a URI (which may or may not be the case): it doesn't matter from nginx' perspective where it always starts with "/".

Comment: @Mortiz Bunkus - Retracted, it seems I am confusing URI with it's (apparently incorrect) use in a software framework I used in the past which for some reason uses it as path

Answer (score 1):

If I remember it correctly, the `^` just sets the Regex rule to match the start of the string.
The parentheses are used to extract that part with the $1-9 variables.

Another solution from the Nginx wiki. [Link](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule)

```
server {
   server_name www.example.com;
   rewrite ^ http://example.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Comment: The `^` is what is confusing me.  I agree with you, usually it means "start of line", but if that were the case, then ^(.*) should grab the whole url, and therefore, `http://example.com$1` should be something like http://example.comwww.example.com, right? If it grabbed the WHOLE url?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `?` after `$request_uri`, does that mean the whole thing is optional? Is that not already the default behavior? ..because I see it a lot of places written without the question mark.